# Free RDMBS With Python Client & Gui Tools For Ubuntu

Tags: python, database, linux

Can any of you recommend a free database engine with a Python client & gui tools (to run queries etc) that is working well with Ubuntu?

I would simply go to MySQL, but from what I know, it's Python client is not being maintained (I am searching for a database engine that has a good, working Python client)

Comment: PostgresQL works really well for me and is very stable.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a python client for PostgreSQL? Is there a GUI for ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, there is - psycopg2 - http://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2

Comment: @praveen: thank you. does it work well with python 2.6.5? is there some good documentation / tutorial for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'd go with PostgreSQL, but [oursql](http://packages.python.org/oursql/).

Comment: Thank you. Is there a python client for PostgreSQL? Is there a GUI for ubuntu?

Comment: I like pgadmin3 for interfacing with pgsql from a gui.